# Why can't Heroku find jar file?

Tags: heroku

I am trying to deploy a Gradle Java app to Heroku using GitHub. The repo name is "v-m-test". This is the Procfile I'm currently using: web: java -jar target/v-m-test.jar. Is this the wrong Procfile?

Comment: is there a jar in that path in GitHub?

Comment: Not that I can see, there doesn't seem to be a jar file for the whole project.

Comment: so how do want them to run your jar?

Comment: My mistake, the jar is there, I was using the incorrect path. Thanks for the help.

Comment: added as answer please accept

Answer (score 0):

make sure the jar is the right path, so in your github you have a jar in this path:
`target/v-m-test.jar`